# Angular directive - how to pass array to ng-repeat and bool to ng-show?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I am following [John Papa](https://github.com/johnpapa/angular-styleguide/blob/master/a1/README.md)'s style guide while developing in Angular 1.x. I want to write a directive that takes an array as an attribute (parameter) and then performs ng-repeat on it. How do I do that? This is my code but it does not work

My HTML snippet. This is how I wolud like to call the directive

```
...
<my-repeat-directive 
 messages="pageController.messages" 
 show="pageController.show">
</my-repeat-directive >
...
```

In the pageController file I have defined messages and show. The values are fetched from the server but here I will just hard code them.

```
...
var vm = this;
vm.messages = ["Message 1", "Message 2", "Longer message 3"];
vm.show = true;
...
```

here is my directive file:

```
angular
  .module('app.directives',[])
  .directive('myRepeatDirective',myRepeatDirective);

function myRepeatDirective() {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    scope: {
      messages: '=',
      show: '=',
    },
    template:'<div ng-repeat="message in messages">' +
             '<p>Message {{message}}</p> </div>' +
             '<p ng-show=show> This is a footer </p>'
  }
}
```

How should I pass the parameter to ng-repat so it realizes it is an array? 
Thanks

Comment: Hmmm, works fine for me.  Can you post the whole html?

Comment: Works for me - http://jsfiddle.net/974juj88/

Comment: you're not closing the div correctly in your template, in the directive

Comment: @Gonzalo.- Despite that it still does work for me.

Comment: Are you sure you're using ng-controller="pageController as pageController" correctly?

Comment: you're not doing the same example.
If you add the var vm = this; and store messages in vm it fails. I can reproduce it changing your fiddle

Comment: @simpleApp use $scope instead of var vm = this and it should work. There is no point of inject it if you're not using it

Comment: This works fine without a closing div AND using vm: https://jsfiddle.net/0tgg9a9z/  $scope vs vm is not the issue.  Removing the closing div repeats the footer however.

Comment: Thanks for the fiddle Rob & Dimitry. I managed to get it working with your help :)